# Ubuntu 16.04 Nvidia driver glitch

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I get this glitch after some time when running the dedicated 940MX on my ThinkPad T460p:

[image]

Note that this glitch does not appear immediately, but rather after a random time when waking up the laptop from sleep.

The following Nvidia driver is currently installed: `nvidia-375`

I also tried the following drivers: `nvidia-378`, `nvidia-370` and all of them have the same problems.

EDIT: After logging out and then logging in again, the glitch goes away.

Comment: I had similar issues with Unity on 14.04 LTS but with xfce didn't notice it. Probably these are some graphic environment incompatibilities

Comment: Ok, good that I'm not the only one. I already thought about installing KDE, but I'm not convinced it would work without reinstalling the whole system

Comment: no need to reinstall a whole system

Comment: I have the same issue with 378.13 driver version. The issue goes out after logging in again but it's quite disturbing. Did you install them via apt or downloaded from website?

Comment: This bug had been reported  :  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/+bug/1667158

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here look!

http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/114232/en-us

**Known Issues with this release:
* Resuming from suspend may not be reliable on GeForce GTX 9xx boards in some configurations.**

Note that many Linux distributions provide their own packages of the NVIDIA Linux Graphics Driver in the distribution's native package management format. This may interact better with the rest of your distribution's framework, and you may want to use this rather than NVIDIA's official package.

Also note that SuSE users should read the SuSE NVIDIA Installer HOWTO before downloading the driver.

Installation instructions: Once you have downloaded the driver, change to the directory containing the driver package and install the driver by running, as root, sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-378.09.run

One of the last installation steps will offer to update your X configuration file. Either accept that offer, edit your X configuration file manually so that the NVIDIA X driver will be used, or run nvidia-xconfig

Note that the list of supported GPU products is provided to indicate which GPUs are supported by a particular driver version. Some designs incorporating supported GPUs may not be compatible with the NVIDIA Linux driver: in particular, notebook and all-in-one desktop designs with switchable (hybrid) or Optimus graphics will not work if means to disable the integrated graphics in hardware are not available. Hardware designs will vary from manufacturer to manufacturer, so please consult with a system's manufacturer to determine whether that particular system is compatible.